# Determinant of map $p(x) \mapsto (Tp)(x)=a_n+a_{n-1}x+ \ldots +a_0x^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomial $\mathbb{R}$ of degree less than or equal to $n$. For $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+ \ldots +a_nx^n$ in $V$. Define a Linear Transformation $T:V \to V$ by $(Tp)(x)=a_n+a_{n-1}x+ \ldots +a_0x^n$ Then
>
> 1. $T$ is one to one
> 2. $T$ is onto
> 3. $T$ is invertible
> 4. $\det T = 1$ or $-1$.

If I take standard basis then I am getting all options correct but if I take $p(x)=3x+3$ then getting last option wrong as value of determinant coming $9$. I know rest of options are right.

Comment: The determinant of a linear operator does not depend on the choice of the basis; so one of your calculations is wrong.

Comment: This is a stupid question, but wouldn't the specific value of the determinant depend on the specific coefficients $a_i$? Provided that they aren't all 0 and hence that T is invertible, the determinant can't be zero, I'm not sure what else to conclude from the problem as stated.

Comment: Why would taking p(x) as 3x + 3 having anything to do with the value of the determinant of T?

Comment: @thedilated then what else we can take? can be take standard basis of R^n

Comment: $p(x) = 3x +3 $is just one vector in V, you cannot compute the value of determinant out of it. The only information you can obtain is perhaps the image of p(x) under T, that's all

Comment: @thedilated ok thanx i got your point

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch:**

The matrix of this linear transformation, in the standard basis for $\mathbf R_n[x]$ is simply the antidiagonal matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&\dots&0&1\\
0&0&0&\dots&1&0\\&\vdots&&&\vdots\\
0&1&0&\dots&0&0\\
1&0&0&\dots&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Now use the definition of the determinant:
$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n+1}}\varepsilon(\sigma)a_{1\sigma(1)}a_{2\sigma(2)}\dots a_{n+1\sigma(n+1)}$$
The only non-zero product in this formula is $a_{1\, n+1}a_{2\,n}\dots a_{n+1\,1}$, which corresponds to the permutation $$ \begin{pmatrix}1&2&\dots&n+1\\n+1&n&\dots&1\end{pmatrix}=(1,n+1)(2,n)\dots (p,p+1)$$
as a product of transpositions, whether $n=2p$ ot $n=2p-1$. Hence the determinant is the signature of this permutation; i.e. $\;\color{red}{(-1)^p}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply twice the map, you get back to where you started: $T(T(p))=p$. By Binet's formula,
$$
(\det T)^2=1
$$
because the identity has determinant $1$. Therefore $\det T=1$ or $\det T=-1$.

Since $\det T\ne0$, the map is invertible, so onto and one-to-one.

Comment: What is Binet's formula?

Comment: @KushalBhuyan $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.

Comment: Oh didn't know that has a name. Got it.